# Why do we need to render variable with @ in front of variable name , in the rails 5 controller, to access the variable in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to pass a JSON response to the props of my React component but I don't want to render it in the server. 
What I find confusing is that when I render the variable with `@` in front of it I can access it in the view, but it doesn't work without otherwise.

#### Code that works

*Controller*

```
class InquiryController < ApplicationController
  def show
    id = params[:id]
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/v1/inquiry/' + id 
    uri = URI(url)
    @inquiry = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    return :json => @inquiry
  end
end
```

*View*

```
<%= react_component('ShowInquiryRootComponent', {inquiry: @inquiry})%>
```

#### Code that doesn't work

*Controller*

```
class InquiryController < ApplicationController
  def show
    id = params[:id]
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/v1/inquiry/' + id 
    uri = URI(url)
    inquiry = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    return :json => inquiry
  end
end
```

*View*

```
<%= react_component('ShowInquiryRootComponent', {inquiry: inquiry})%>
```

Comment: You don't always have to. In fact using instance variables in views might be frowned upon by testers! You could pass locals couldn't you, when using `render` of course? See [Passing Local Variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) for details. Also, shouldn't this design be manipulating the json response in the view instead of trying to access the `@inquiry` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do:

```
def show
  ...
  inquiry = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  return :json => inquiry
end
```

Then this way you're creating `inquiry` as a local variable. Local variables can't be accessed from any other place more than the scope in which they were created. In this way that variable won't "go out" from the show method.

The way you can achieve, passing variables from controller to view as you want to do in the `InquiryController` is to do it creating it as an *instance* variable, those which you call the variable with an `@` (at) in front of it. This way, that variable could be sent from your controller's method to the corresponding view.

For example, if you create a local variable called `bla` inside a method in the controller, and then you want to access this variable in any view, then you'll see an error like:

```
NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `bla' for #...
```

Rails will try to find that variable in the current "position" it's, that's, the view, and if in the view there's no any `bla` variable defined, then it'll raise such error.

Passing a variable from the controller to the view as an instance `@` variable is the way to deal with it, and Rails work this way.

I can quote from an old answer:

> Instance variables are unique to the instance of an object and can be
>   used in any of its method.  Local variable are only used inside one
>   method.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Would be awesome to see more details.